# Flex web application control equivalent to mx.controls.HTML

Tags: apache-flex, web-applications, controls

As Flex web applications do not have the mx.controls.HTML control (which is for AIR applications only), anyone know of a FOSS custom control that can near the functionality. I have checked the flex-iframe control, but it offers only viewing of HTML content and not manipulation as in the AIR control.

Thanks to all in advance.

Comment: Hi , did you figured out a solution for this question ?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, there is no built-in HTML control within the Flex SDK.

One workaround would be to manipulate your flex iframe content using ExternalInterface to exchange messages between Flex & JavaScript